# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'A' to data type int

Tags: c#, asp.net

Conversion failed when converting the `nvarchar` value 'A' to data type `int`.

```
private void linksdetail(string id)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(con_string);
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" select a.solution_title,b.solution_sub_id,b.solutions_id,a.url from cms_solution_viewnew a, cms_solution_viewnew b where a.row_id = b.solution_sub_id  and b.solutions_id='" + id + "'", con);

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.Read())
    {

        HyperLink1.Text = dr["solution_title"].ToString();

        HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = dr["url"].ToString();

    }
    dr.Close();
    con.Close();
}
```

How to solve it please help me.

Comment: What is the type of `b.solutions_id` column? What is the type and value of `id`? Looks like a numeric one. You should not use single quotes in a numeric columns. As a better way, use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: @soner solutions_id is int type

Comment: solutions_id  column data type is integer type and value of id is 9

Comment: This problem is just one of the reasons one should never create SQL statements by concatenating strings. Parameterized queries are safer, faster *and* cleaner to write

Answer (score 1):

> solutions_id column data type is integer type and value of id is 9

Error message is pretty self explanatory. You try to assign sequence of characters to `int` typed column. Based on your example values, you don't need to use single quotes with your numeric columns. You can change your

```
b.solutions_id = '" + id + "'"
```

to

```
b.solutions_id = " + id
```

but as a better way, use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` automatically instead of calling `Close` methods manually.

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection(con_string))
using(var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "select a.solution_title,b.solution_sub_id,b.solutions_id,a.url from cms_solution_viewnew a, cms_solution_viewnew b where a.row_id = b.solution_sub_id  and b.solutions_id = @id";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
    con.Open();
    using(var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // Do your stuff
    }
}
```